# QDateTime::fromString returns invalid Date, what am I missing?

Tags: c++, qt, qdatetime

I have some code that reads a datetime from a sqlite database, the datetime is returned as a string. when I try to convert it to a date using QDateTime::FromString it returns an invalid date. Below is the time as returned from the database and conversion. 
Why is this failing to parse?

```
// -this is the value returned from the DB currentServerTime=2012-01-17 19:20:27.0

QString format("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
QString qCurrentServerTime(currentServerTime);
now = QDateTime::fromString(qCurrentServerTime, format);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No expert in QT, but if `QDateTime::fromString()` works as one would (reasonably) expect and according to [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromString-2), you're not using the correct pattern.

You indicate the string read from the sqllite database is like "2012-01-17 19:20:27.0", then your format should be like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.z`.

In detail:

- Your separator should by '-' not '/' (as you show in the example)
- The time seems to be in 24 hours format (19 -> 7 p.m.) (so use `HH` instead of `hh`)
- You have one digit for milliseconds, so add `.z`.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong time, I did modify the format to match what I posted and that works. moving back to my actual date/time I cannot get this to work.

Comment: @user1127081 So your actual string is formatted like you suggest with your format? Good. Then what doesn't work now?

Comment: Thanks, I posted the wrong datetime (the correct one 2012/01/17 12:00:00 AM) but you did lead me to my mistake(I also realize we have serveral d/t formats in our table). Below is the correct format. "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AP" Thanks again

Comment: I found a much better way to manage the date conversion -Boost. PTime is much more forgiving in the event the format changes. boost::posix_time::ptime    openTime(boost::posix_time::time_from_string("2012/01/17 12:00:00 AM")));